# Remote Session + Remote Session from Inside first session = Smart SIzing not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-11, display-settings, code

I've looked around a fair bit in search of an answer, but no luck so far.

The issue I have, is that I have a work laptop and a personal desktop with 3 monitors.

I remote into the work laptop from the personal desktop to utilize two of the 3 monitors.

When I'm full screen and running the RDP session from desktop, I need to access resources behind another RDP accessible by VPN from the work laptop.

If I use Microsoft Remote Desktop App on from work laptop, everything scales beautifully.

But if I use regular .rdp file and Microsoft Remote Desktop to access a secondary rdp session from within the first session, the secondary sessions window does not scale properly.

I have tried appending 'dynamic resolution:i:1' and 'smart sizing:i:1' but neither result in the desired effect.

If smart sizing is enabled, everything in the 2nd RDP session is small and blurry. If its disabled, then I need to use scroll bars to navigate.

I've tried adjusting the desktop resolution in the .rdp file, but then it won't full screen properly. The Microsoft Remote Desktop App doesn't have this issue, scales without problem in this setup.

The desktop has 3 monitors that utilize 1920x1080 res, the laptop utilizes 1366x768, I imagine the client is picking up the remote resolution from first session and trying to scale that which is making it buggered, but not sure how to fix...

I don't want to use third party options as this is for a corporate environment with strict security policies.

Below is a sanitized copy of my rdp session in text format.

```
screen mode id:i:1
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,799,143,1853,948
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:xxx.xxx.xx.xx
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectlocation:i:0
smart sizing:i:1
redirectwebauthn:i:1
enablerdsaadauth:i:0
dynamic resolution:i:1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

edit: I forgot to add the initial sessions .rdp info, the only difference between it and this one is it uses the selectedmonitors:s:value (value = 0,1)